# Given an AR signal, find its PSD, its autocorrelation function

Tags: discrete-signals, autocorrelation, autoregressive-model

I am studying discrete-random signal processing, Could anyone tell me by an example or reference what it means by the following?

> Given an AR signal, find its PSD (power spectral density), its autocorrelation function.

First of all, I cannot find an example of an AR signal. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"AR" stands for Autoregressive which are all pole systems, where a given output is based on the current input and previous outputs. This is in contrast to "MA" or Moving Average which are all zero systems, where a given output is based on the current input and previous inputs. A system with both poles and zeros is "ARMA".

Here is a nice presentation from Imperial College London with examples of finding power spectral densities and autocorrelation functions for such processes:

[https://www.commsp.ee.ic.ac.uk/~mandic/ASP_Slides/ASP_Lecture_2_ARMA_Modelling_2019.pdf](https://www.commsp.ee.ic.ac.uk/%7Emandic/ASP_Slides/ASP_Lecture_2_ARMA_Modelling_2019.pdf)